# What are each block type's functions?

Tags: infiniminer

I.e., I don't know the difference between a colored block and a road block.

Comment: Colored blocks are prettier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the following blocks:

- **Coloured blocks** can be built cheaply.
- **Road blocks** let you move twice as fast.
- **Transparent coloured blocks** or force-fields only allow one team through.
- **Bank blocks** work as banks for one team only.
- **Beacon blocks** show up on your team's radar.
- **Jump blocks** are trampolines.
- **Ladder blocks** let you climb up.
- **Explosive blocks and shock blocks** are very dangerous indeed. Explosives can destroy enemy blocks. Normally, you cannot destroy blocks placed the by enemy team.

The following blocks occur naturally:

- **Lava blocks** flow to fill empty space, and kill you.
- **Dirt** does nothing, but you can dig through it.
- **Ore, gold and diamond** are valuables. You mine these and collect the spoils.